# flutter problem with scrolling in nested tab bar and nested columns

Tags: flutter, dart

i have nested TabBar and nested columns and i need to make vertical scrolling but the scrolling is not working
it only works if i added a fixed height at the parent widget. is there any other ways to make it scrollable without giving a fixed height

you can find my code bellow

```
  @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DefaultTabController(
      length: 2,
      child: Container(
        // height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 3.5,
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Container(
              child: TabBar(
                  indicator: const BoxDecoration(
                    color: kHyperTextColor,
                  ),
                  onTap: (value) {
                    context.read<LayoutProvider>().footballTabIndex = value;
                  },
                  tabs: [
                    Tab(
                        child: Text(
                      AppLocalizations.of(context)!.all,
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14.sp),
                    )),
                    Tab(
                        child: Text(
                      AppLocalizations.of(context)!.locale,
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14.sp),
                    )),
                  ]),
            ),

            BannerScreen(
              logo:
                  context.watch<TournamentDetailsProvider>().tournament.logo ??
                      "",
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: TabBarView(children: const [
                TournamentDetailsGenericBody(),
                TournamentDetailsGenericBody(),
              ]),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

and

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DefaultTabController(
      length: 2,
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Container(
            child: TabBar(
                isScrollable: true,
                ),
                tabs: [
                  Tab(
                      child: Text(
                    AppLocalizations.of(context)!.genericView,
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14.sp),
                  )),
                  Tab(
                      child: Text(
                    AppLocalizations.of(context)!.mathces,
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14.sp),
                ]),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: TabBarView(children: [
              GenericView(),
              MatchesView(),
            ]),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
```

any help would be appreciated thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found an alternative way which is removing the tabbarview here is the code

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SingleChildScrollView(
      child: DefaultTabController(
        length: 5,
        child: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: [
            Container(
              margin: EdgeInsetsDirectional.only(bottom: 30.h),
              color: kSecondTabBarColor,
              child: TabBar(
                  isScrollable: true,
                  indicator: const BoxDecoration(
                    color: kHyperTextColor,
                  ),
                  onTap: (value) {
                    context.read<LayoutProvider>().footballTabIndex = value;
                    context.pop();
                  },
                  tabs: [
                    Tab(
                        child: Text(
                      AppLocalizations.of(context)!.all,
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14.sp),
                    )),
                    Tab(
                        child: Text(
                      AppLocalizations.of(context)!.locale,
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14.sp),
                    )),
                    Tab(
                        child: Text(
                      AppLocalizations.of(context)!.globalism,
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14.sp),
                    )),
                    Tab(
                        child: Text(
                      AppLocalizations.of(context)!.african,
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14.sp),
                    )),
                    Tab(
                        child: Text(
                      AppLocalizations.of(context)!.ballKings,
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14.sp),
                    )),
                  ]),
            ),
            const SimpleTeamComponent(),
            SizedBox(
              height: 28.h,
            ),
            BannerScreen(
              logo:
                  context.watch<TournamentDetailsProvider>().tournament.logo ??
                      "",
              logoHeight: 90.h,
              logoWidth: 90.w,
              name:
                  context.watch<TournamentDetailsProvider>().tournament.title ??
                      "",
            ),
            const TournamentDetailsGenericBody(),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

and

```
  Widget renderChildBody() {
    switch (context.watch<TournamentDetailsProvider>().tabId) {
      case 0:
        return GenericView();
      case 1:
        return MatchesView();
      case 2:
        return TournamentRankingView();
      case 3:
        return TournamentStatisticsView();
      case 4:
        return TournamentHistoryView();
      default:
        return GenericView();
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DefaultTabController(
      length: 5,
      child: Column(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: [
          Container(
            margin: EdgeInsetsDirectional.only(bottom: 30.h),
            color: kSecondTabBarColor,
            child: TabBar(
                onTap: (index) {
                  context.read<TournamentDetailsProvider>().tabId = index;
                },
                isScrollable: true,
                indicator: const BoxDecoration(
                  color: kHyperTextColor,
                ),
                tabs: [
                  Tab(
                      child: Text(
                    AppLocalizations.of(context)!.genericView,
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14.sp),
                  )),
                  Tab(
                      child: Text(
                    AppLocalizations.of(context)!.mathces,
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14.sp),
                  )),
                  Tab(
                      child: Text(
                    AppLocalizations.of(context)!.theRanking,
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14.sp),
                  )),
                  Tab(
                      child: Text(
                    AppLocalizations.of(context)!.statistics,
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14.sp),
                  )),
                  Tab(
                      child: Text(
                    AppLocalizations.of(context)!.tournamentHistory,
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14.sp),
                  )),
                ]),
          ),
          renderChildBody()
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```